# PE Explorer vs. Debugger differences

Tags: debugging, pe, shellcode

I injected shellcode into an executable. 
Entrypoint is set to first shellcode instruction.

Shellcode: 
nop 
nop 
label: 
nop 
nop 
jmp 
label 
nop
nop

which translate to: \x90\x90\x90\x90\xeb\xfc\x90\x90

Correct Values in PE can be seen with PE-Explorer

[image: pe explorer]

There are other values displayed in the debugger which translate to wrong instructions.

[image: debugger]

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: is this PE-Explorer from there?
http://www.heaventools.com
Never knew it could show the instructions